# Text left to enumeration labels

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

If I enumerate like this

```
\textbf{Problem 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\textit{\alph*})]
\item Random Text
\item Random Text
\item Random Text
\end{enumerate}
```

then how can I accomplish to write something at the left of the labels on the margin, like **8 pts** and **9 pts** in the following picture:

[image: exam]

Comment: Did you copy this code snippet from the actual exam? If so, can you make use of the remaining code to generate the desired layout?

Comment: @Mico I wrote down what is written in the exam (I added a picture)

Comment: @Mico Yes, sorry, I refer to the bold caraters 8 pts, etc. I would like to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the points may change on an `\item`-by-`\item` basis, insert the points manually via `\insertpts{<num>}` below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\NewDocumentCommand{\insertpts}{ m }{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\small\bfseries #1 pts\hspace{3em}}%
  \ignorespaces}
  
\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{Problem 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item \insertpts{9}
  Random Text
  \item \insertpts{8}
  Random Text
  \item \insertpts{7}
  Random Text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the font specifications (currently set to `\small\bfseries`) and the gap by adjusting the elements inside `\hspace` (currently set to `3em`).

Comment: That's brilliant!